# Android - INSERT in mysql database when I click a button

Tags: android, mysql, database

Here's the problem :
There's a button in a view. When user click that button, insert a column to a table happened.
I have read tutorial to connect mysql to android but I still can't solve this problem. And I have search in google but still can't find. I hope there's solution to finish my problem...

View MAIN

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/MAIN_tittle"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    android:scaleX="1.2"
    android:scaleY="1.2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/main_tittle" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/MAIN_play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleX="0.7"
    android:scaleY="0.7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/MAIN_tittle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/main_play" />
```

CLASS MAIN

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {
ImageButton playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.MAIN_play);
ImageButton optionsButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.MAIN_options);
ImageButton quitButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.MAIN_quit);
ImageButton facebookButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.MAIN_facebook);
ImageButton twitterButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.MAIN_twitter);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
    //PROBLEM IN MANIFEST
    play(); 
    options(); 
    quit(); 
    goToFacebook(); 
    rating();   
}

private void play() {
    playButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {  startActivity(new Intent("com.example.creativesnakeladder.CharactersChoice"));
            //this is area of codes which to insert a column in mysql database
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant code you have produced so far.

Comment: @Qben I just read tutorial show data from mysql to android. And, the formula is add query in php not in java.

Comment: Do you have anything at all at time stage? Like the `View` and the `Button` just showing a `Toast` message when pressed. I get the impression you need to learn Android development in general, and not just the connection toward a database. Could be wrong though. :)

Comment: good though. sorry, make you waiting. because i must edit first

Answer (score 1):

Android uses [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) to manage "on-disk" persistence in the traditional sense. Here is the [package summary](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) as well as a [recent tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/blog/android-sqlite-tutorial/). Once you understand the basics, you can move on to using something like [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml) to abstract some of the boilerplate away for you.

Comment: is there a manner to use mysql easily when people use mysql in development android app

Comment: No, I can't say that I know of anyone using mysql in an Android app instead of the provided SQLite. If you are truly needing MySQL for this, I'm not much help. Sorry :(